# Computational Complexity of Parallel Algorithms

Tags: computational-complexity, trees

Does parallelism factor in when deriving the computational complexity of a parallel algorithm?

Suppose I have a perfect binary tree $T$ with leaves numbered $1$ to $n$, and an algorithm $\operatorname{Sum}()$ that computes the sum $1 + 2 + \dotsb + n$ in this way:

$\operatorname{Sum}(T)=$

If $T$ is a leaf node $k$, return $k$. Otherwise,

1. $a \leftarrow \operatorname{Sum}(\text{left subtree of }T)$
2. $b \leftarrow \operatorname{Sum}(\text{right subtree of }T)$
3. Return $a + b$.

The total number of additions performed is $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \dotsb + n/2$. However, if steps (1) and (2) are performed in parallel, is the computational complexity $O(\log n)$ instead?

Answer (score 3):

You (or the compiler) would have to rewrite the algorithm, but as long as you had at least $n/2$ processors and communication between them could be done in constant time, then the parallel version would indeed have running time $O(\log n)$, since all of the work at a given level could be done (in parallel) at the same time.

**Added**. If we're restricted to a fixed number, $k$, of processors we first observe that the top $k+1$ layers (consisting of $O(k)$ nodes) can be added in $O(\log k)$ steps in parallel, as I noted above. However, for a tree with $N>2^k$ nodes, that will still leave us with $O(N-2^k)$ additions to perform and we can only compute these in $O((N-2^k)/k)$ time in parallel. Consequently, it will take $O(\log k +(N-2^k)/k)=O(N)$ steps, in general, to sum the nodes in a tree of size $N$.

Comment: But don't we usually assume that we have a constant number of processors? Does that bottleneck affect the complexity?

Comment: For theoretical purposes, we don't necessarily assume a constant number of processors. In situations where the number of processors is fixed, then, yes, it makes a difference. I'll expand on my answer after I come back from my classes.